# Let X be a subset of M. Show that X is bounded if and only if there exists z in M such that.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a subset of $M$. Show that $X$ is bounded ( there exists $a$ in $M$ such that $d(x,y) \leq a$ for all $x,y$ in $M$) if
and only if there exists $z$ in $M$ and $r > 0$ such that $d(x,z) < r$ for all
$x$ in $X$, in other words, $X \subset B(z,r)$

I don't really know how to get started on this.

Comment: d(x, r) should be d(x, z)

Comment: No, it's d(x,r)<r, that's what the problem says.

Comment: @MichaelCera Then the problem is wrong. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: The problem has a typo.  d() has to take points of M as input.  If r > 0 then it is (supposedly) a real number. M doesn't necessarily have an order.

Comment: The problem does this typo twice.  it should be "(there exists an $a$ in $\mathbb R$ such that ...".  As the problem is written it simply does not make sense d() always returns a non-negative value.  Not a point of M.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is bounded (and non-empty), with constant $a$. Fix any $z$ in $X$. Then $X \subseteq B(z, 2a)$, quite trivially.

Also, if $X \subseteq B(z,r)$, we know that for all $x,y \in X$, $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y) < r + r = 2r$ by the triangle inequality again. So use $a = 2r$ to see that $X$ is then bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Think visually about what it is saying.  A set is bounded if the distance between any two points is at most a certain amount.  Now you need to prove that is the same thing as saying a set has a point in it such that the point is at most a certain distance from every other point.

Does that seem reasonable?  It does to me because if the point is at most a certain distance apart from two points, the two points must be at most some distance apart.  And vice versa, if any two points are bounded in distance then any point is at most a distance from any other point.

So how to put that in "analysis language".    Well comparing distances of two points from a third is the triangle inequality. And distance is d.

So if for all $x,y \in X; d(x,y) < M$ then pick a point,z,  for any $x \in X$ $d(z,x) < M$.  So that's half the proof.

If there is a point, w, and an N s.t. for all $y \in X; d(w, y) < N$ then for any $x, y \in X$ then $d(x,y )\le d(x,w) + d(w,y) < N + N = 2N$ so X is bounded.

Done.